# 1 [main] MyTask 12376 _cygtls::handle_exceptions: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: c

When I use below two lines in program am getting error as

```
1 [main] MyTask 12376 _cygtls::handle_exceptions: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
   2597 [main] MyTask 12376 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to MyTask.exe.stackdump
    int ch_of_file1 = 0;
    ch_of_file1 = getc(fp1);
```

May I know the reason?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As StackOverflow is not meant to be used as a forum to help you debug your code. You may also want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get more familiar with SO and what is expected.

Comment: My crystal ball says that `fp1` is not a valid, open file stream. If you want more than just speculation, please post a [mcve].